# Compiling given CGAL example on polyfit

Tags: cgal, gmp, vcpkg

i have linked the gmplib to the following example https://doc.cgal.org/5.0.4/Polygonal_surface_reconstruction/index.html
on windows and visual studio

but i got the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __gmpn_neg_n referenced in function "private: static struct CGAL::Mpzf __cdecl CGAL::Mpzf::aors(struct CGAL::Mpzf const &,struct CGAL::Mpzf const &,int)" (?aors@Mpzf@CGAL@@CA?AU12@AEBU12@0H@Z) cgal-polyfit
```

Comment: Did you link with gmp and mpfr?

Comment: I have linked with gmp and mpfr

Comment: Did you configure CGAL in Header only mode?

Comment: yes and i use vcpkg-master to install the CGAL ,then I added the lib to the linker